# MouseEnter a hit area causes panel to fly-in and fill the hit area

Tags: wpf, events, animation, mouse

I feel like I've tried everything to make this work right.  I have a rectangle with a MouseEnter and MouseLeave event that cause the fly-in animation to start and stop.  The problem is, when the fly-in arrives, it covers the rectangle, and causes the MouseLeave event to fire because the mouse is no longer on the rectangle.  The panel starts offscreen and has a scaleTransform and translateTransform applied as an animation.  Everything is done in Blend.

It's easy to animate something that causes the trigger itself.  It seems to be more difficult to animate something separate from the trigger object, but then covers the trigger object.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved it by checking the IsMouseOver property every time MouseEnter and MouseLeave get called for both the rectangle hit area AND the panel.

```
    private bool isMouseOverRightPanelOrHitRect()
    {
        if (mRightPanel.IsMouseOver || rightHitRect.IsMouseOver)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    private void handleRightPanelAnimation(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isMouseOverRightPanelOrHitRect())
            mRightPanel_FlyOn();
        else
            mRightPanel_FlyOff();
    }

    private void mRightPanel_FlyOn()
    {
        if (!mRightPanel.Docked)
            VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(mCanvas, rightOn.Name, true);
    }

    private void mRightPanel_FlyOff()
    {
        if (!mRightPanel.Docked)
            VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(mCanvas, rightOff.Name, true);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the IsHitTestVisible="False" property, you can set this on the rectangle that's supposed to fly in to prevent it taking mouse input.

Comment: I have played around with it, but it doesn't seem to be working as expected.  Perhaps I'm just doing something wrong...

Comment: If you post some of the XAML that you're using to drive the rectangle movement I might be able to see what's wrong, if it's too sensitive then see if you can come up with a small example that would do the same thing.

Comment: I'll try to get some code together soon.  I want the rectangle to receive the mouseleave event in case the user leaves the area before the fly-in fully arrives, at which point the fly-in will just fly back out.  So I can't set IsHitTestVisible to false until the animation is finished.  But by that point the mouse is already over the new panel, and not over the rectangle anymore.

Comment: Perhaps I should try IsMouseDirectlyOverChanged.  I'm thinking that may be the best way to handle this.

Comment: Crap.  That didn't work.  What I really need is IsMouseOverChanged.  Any ideas?